# How to preview a DVI (rather than a PDF) in TeXstudio

Tags: compiling, texstudio, preview, dvi, dvi-mode

TeXstudio is very slow when compiling and previewing a 400-page book.  I was told that previewing a DVI is faster than PDF, so I want to preview a DVI instead. How do I do that in TeXstudio? By default, it is previewing a PDF. I have a lot of Math, a lot of \includegraphics, 12 chapters, and I need to update the whole book to review the links to citations and references.

Comment: a dvi previewer typically can not show scalable font formats or graphics or drawn curves such as tikz/pstricks it may be faster but it may not show what you want. You don't say what operating system you are on, I use xdvi but other dvi previewers exist

Comment: can you not use `\includeonly` and just preview one chapter at a time, that is likely to make a much bigger speed difference. (and can still include the bibliography so can preview citation links)

Comment: I was using \input. I changed to \include and using \includeonly is awesome. I just work on one chapter at a time, all the citations and links to other chapters are still there. Thank you! No need for DVI preview anymore!